# Open swagger-editor-bundle.js with brackets

Tags: javascript, swagger

I have downloaded the swagger editor, and now I have need to modify the source code in order to support the coap protocol.
I'm trying to open the file swagger-editor-bundle.js in the dist folder, with the editor Brackets, but when I do this it show me the code without indentation and report a lot of errors.
Can you tell me please where I am wrong?
I need to study the source code in order to learn how swagger works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to edit a file which is being compiled into the dist folder, what you would do in this situation is go to their Github repo and look in the src directory:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/tree/master/src

Then take a look at their build process for you to re-compile the project:

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/blob/master/package.json#L18